# Why does holding a non-Send type across an await point result in a non-Send Future?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, future

In the documentation for the [`Send` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html), there is a nice example of how something like Rc is not `Send`, since cloning/dropping in two different threads can cause the reference count to get out of sync.

What is less clear, however, is why holding a binding to a non-`Send` type across an `await` point in an `async fn` causes the generated future to also be non-`Send`. I was able to find a work around for when the compiler has been too conservative in the [work-arounds chapter](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/07_workarounds/03_send_approximation.html) of the async handbook, but it does not go as far as answering the question that I am asking here.

Perhaps someone could shed some light on this with an example of why having a non-`Send` type in a `Future` is ok, but holding it across an `await` is not?

Comment: Everything you hold on to across an `await` needs to be stored in the future, since the function returns at this point, storing its state. And if you store something that's not `Send` in a future, the future itself can't be `Send`.

Comment: That does seem pretty intuitive now that you have said it like that. So what is the situation where I pass something that is not `Send` as an argument to an `async fn`, which has being called to generate the `Future` but has not yet been polled. I guess under the hood these arguments are also stored inside the generated `Future`?

Comment: That depends on how the `async fn` uses it. If the `async fn` consumes it before `await`-ing then the future would not need to store it, and should thus be Send.

Comment: @Masklinn Even if the async fn consumes the argument(s) before first `await`, I think the future will still need to store them. When the async fn is called, it returns the future immediately, and AFAIK the body of the function doesn't start executing until `poll()` is invoked on the future.

Comment: Yes, this is one of the differences between `async fn foo()` and `fn bar() -> impl Future`: `bar` can do work immediately upon being called, whereas `foo` has to store all its arguments and wait to be polled.

Comment: @user4815162342 ah true, that's also a difference between `async` functions and functions with an `async` block, probably.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you use `.await` in an async function, the compiler builds a state machine behind the scenes. Each `.await` introduces a new state (while it waits for something) and the code in between are state transitions (aka tasks), which will be triggered based on some external event (e.g. from IO or a timer etc).

Each task gets scheduled to be executed by the async runtime, which *could* choose to use a different thread from the previous task. If the  state transition is not safe to be sent between threads then the resulting `Future` is also not `Send` so that you get a compilation error if you try to execute it in a multi-threaded runtime.

It is completely OK for a `Future` *not* to be `Send`, it just means you can only execute it in a single-threaded runtime.

---

> Perhaps someone could shed some light on this with an example of why having a non-`Send` type in a `Future` is ok, but holding it across an `await` is not?

Consider the following simple example:

```
async fn add_votes(current: Rc<Cell<i32>>, post: Url) {
    let new_votes = get_votes(&post).await;
    *current += new_votes;
}
```

The compiler will construct a state machine like this (simplified):

```
enum AddVotes {
    Initial {
        current: Rc<Cell<i32>>,
        post: Url,
    },
    WaitingForGetVotes { 
        current: Rc<Cell<i32>>,
        fut: GetVotesFut,
    },
}
```

```
impl AddVotes {
    fn new(current: Rc<Cell<i32>>, post: Url) {
        AddVotes::Initial { current, post }
    }

    fn poll(&mut self) -> Poll {
        match self {
            AddVotes::Initial(state) => {
                let fut = get_votes(&state.post);
                *self = AddVotes::WaitingForGetVotes {
                     current: state.current,
                     fut
                }
                Poll::Pending
            }
            AddVotes::WaitingForGetVotes(state) => {
                if let Poll::Ready(votes) = state.fut.poll() {
                    *state.current += votes;
                    Poll::Ready(())
                } else {
                    Poll::Pending
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In a multithreaded runtime, each call to `poll` could be from a different thread, in which case the runtime would *move* the `AddVotes` to the other thread before calling `poll` on it. This won't work because `Rc` cannot be sent between threads.

However, if the future just used an `Rc` within the *same* state transition, it would be fine, e.g. if `votes` was just an `i32`:

```
async fn add_votes(current: i32, post: Url) -> i32 {
    let new_votes = get_votes(&post).await;

    // use an Rc for some reason:
    let rc = Rc::new(1);
    println!("rc value: {:?}", rc);

    current + new_votes
}
```

In which case, the state machine would look like this:

```
enum AddVotes {
    Initial {
        current: i32,
        post: Url,
    },
    WaitingForGetVotes { 
        current: i32,
        fut: GetVotesFut,
    },
}
```

The `Rc` isn't captured in the state machine because it is created and dropped within the state transition (task), so the whole state machine (aka `Future`) is still `Send`.